# Spring security reactive mixing HttpBasic + Oauth2

Tags: spring, security, spring-webflux, basic-authentication, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to have a Security Webflux configuration where I am able to login using httpBasic for some resources and the rest of the resources with oAuth

Far now I haven't been able to understand how to do it; it seems, that in non reactive way, can be achieved using some kind of realm name or whatever but in reactive that doesn't exist, I think it is because is related to the workflow of the thread or something related to that in the web filter chain

However I have the following far now in kotlin,

```
return http.httpBasic().authenticationManager {...}
    .and()
       .oauth2ResourceServer()
          .jwt()
          .and()
    .and()
    .authorizeExchange()
    .pathMatchers(* noAuthPaths).permitAll()
    .pathMatchers(* basicAuthPaths).authenticated()
    .anyExchange().access{...}
    .and().csrf().disable()
    .build()
```

Check that **noAuthPaths** and **basicAuthPaths** are just arrays of string patterns, and the last array(**basicAuthPaths**) is the one that I want to use using HttpBasic.

If I call the resource in the browser, and it is listed in the **basicAuthPaths**, I want that the login pops asking for the Basic Auth credential. And if not I would expect the Bearer token.

With the current configuration if I call the resources using Basic Auth in postman I can access all resources the listed in the array and those that comes from anyExchange method. Also if I enter the resource in the browser the login form doesn't pop.

Does anybody know how to support both strategies for different resources? Thanks.

## Update 1 (Suggestion failing)

I tried what is suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68628700/1428872)  with no success.

I have created a simple [example](https://github.com/dbranco/howto-security) using Okta as OAuth IDP.

In the case of using different Beans with Order annotation I am not able to make it run, always getting a 403 status, and if access to the one is suppose to be basic auth it also asks for the Okta authentication.

With only one Bean configuration at least I manage to see the answer from the secureoauth endpoint, and the securebasic endpoint reject due to the access strategy.

In both cases OAuth authentication is always call.

## Update 2 (Suggetion With Success)

Thanks to @greiker suggestion, he added a PR in my example where you can find it [here](https://github.com/dbranco/howto-security/pull/1#pullrequestreview-722316552)

In the pull request you can find some of my review comments that will implement for the Okta use case and push to let people check whenever they need, however the changes suggested won't be deleted since they cover a broader case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code shown comes from a `@Configuration` class. You could split your configuration into multiple classes and add `@Order(1)` on the first where you configure basic auth (eventually with `permitAll` for these path) and refuse connection for OAuth URLs

Then `@Order(2)` on the second where you configure OAuth with its path.

Mixing both in same file will just give you headaches but could be done through `AuthenticationEntryPoint` I believe.

Comment: That would be true if  I have the regular web security, but this is reactive programming so the security configuration is a little different. Could you elaborate for the AuthenticationEntryPoint suggestion?

Comment: There is no difference, you make a copy and you set an order.

Comment: I have been trying to do what you have suggest with no success. I have created a simple test using Okta as OAuth IDP (https://github.com/dbranco/howto-security). In the case of using different Beans with Order annotation I am not able to make it run, always getting a 403 status, and if access to the one is suppose to be basic auth it ask also for the Okta authentication. With only one Bean configuration at least I manage to see the answer from the secureoauth endpoint, and the securebasic endpoint reject due to the access strategy. In both cases  OAuth authentication is always call

Comment: I'm not sure if multiple Bean with Order would work, I was think of multiple class with @Order (although it might work). In any cases, you need to permitAll the other URLs so that the you only get one auth check. I also think that the properties for jwt are incorrect. Should be `spring.security.oauth2.provider.okta.issuer-uri` and `spring.security.oauth2.registration.okta.client-id` etc... That is probably why you get 403

Comment: I've added a Pull Request to your code that works https://github.com/dbranco/howto-security/pull/1 trick is that you need a securityMatcher for reactive config

Comment: @grekier thanks for the interested you have shown in the question, I am pleased to say that your PR is working, even though I will just add a little change with a comment in order to let people know the difference between having the header www-authnticate + response 401 and only response 401

Comment: No problems at all. My pleasure. A last note on the solution is that you will need to cover all URLs called in your application with securityMatcher patterns. Meaning that, if you call a URL that doesn't match any, it will throw an exception